# There's a way to sort the SPAuditQuery at Query construction level?

Tags: auditing, spaudit

If we have

```
SPAuditQuery auditQuery = new SPAuditQuery(context.Site);

auditQuery.RestrictToListItem(item);


auditQuery.RowLimit = (uint)numberOfEvents;
auditQuery.SetRangeStart(startRange);
auditQuery.SetRangeEnd(endRage);
```

It will return the records in a descending order, I can then sort that results but if the user set a RowLimit, start and end Range Date, there's a big change that I will just get the results from the startRange and I'm insterested in show the most recent audits.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: when you create a SPAuditQuery, you can set options like RowLimit, SetRangeStart, SetRangeEnd and so on, before calling the GetEntries Method (context.Site.Audit.GetEntries(auditQuery);), the query results (entries) are sorted by Ocurred date Ascending, my question is if there's a way to change that.